# Modelling a full Windsor knot on a necktie

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel

I'm trying to model the steps involved in tying a full Windsor knot. The very first step is getting the fatter/thicker end through a loop. In my model, towards achieving this first step, I reached this stage:

[image: Windsor Knot - Necktie Intermediate Step Starting Position]

To make this, I've used a Bezier Curve and added a Nurb Circle with very low thickness to its Bevel. I got the thin and thicker ends by changing the radius of different control points. I plan to convert this to mesh once the steps are complete.

My goal is to reach a more refined version:

[image: Windsor Knot - Necktie Intermediate Step Final Position]

However, I've only manages this:

[image: Windsor Knot - Necktie Intermediate Step My Result]

As you can see, the loop made as a result of the thicker end wrapping around the thinner end is quite large. I would like to make this loop as small as possible with two surfaces just touching each other.

My main difficulty is doing just that. My main strategy is to subdivide and use as many control points as possible. However, when I get the surfaces closer to touch each other, the model goes haywire, the surfaces crumple up and I'm not able to correct this even with the tilts and adding/removing subdivides. So basically, my question can also be reduced to if the Bezier curve can wrap around a part of itself.

I've just started with Blender 2.8 about a month ago and am quite the newbie.

Comment: "*My main strategy is to subdivide and use as many control points as possible.*" That sounds harmful and even unhelpful. Use as little as possible controls points to achieve the required results with acceptable quality. It will be both easier to control and improve performance.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, if you require an animation or static result, but it sounds like it would be a lot easier to use a "tie shaped" flat mesh object, with a curve modifier shaping it, to a bezier curve then move the object around. That way you can keep the curve live without converting to mesh

Answer (score 8):

As Duarte said, the Curve Modifier is probably best suited for this.
You can easily edit both the knot and the shape of your tie.

1. Start with a flat tie. Heavily subdivide it along it's length
2. Create the Windsor knot using a Bezier curve
3. Add a *Curve modifier* to your tie and target the knot

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!
I am trying to make the knot tight once it is "knoted". I tried both curves and meshes by fixing one end and applying force to the other, but I didn't manage to actually move it properly and I also had problems with self collission. Do you have an idea how I can use physics to do that? Or any other idea?

Comment: Hey :). Could you please ask it as a new question? You can link this one to provide context. I'm not an animator, but we have some guys here who could help :).