# Make array follow torus knot

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I want to have Array modifier follow a torus knot. Maybe there is another method to have the rings follow the torus?

The threads I have found here usually are trying to have array follow a curve (like Bezier curve), which is not regular mesh.

[image]
Got the .blend file here.

I just want the rings to follow the taurus knot.
Thanks for the time to look at my problem.

Comment: you can make a curve from your knot, and use this curve as the Object of a Curve modifier. To share files, use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Would I then select the knot it self or just a line from the knot? I am fairly new in this :)

Comment: you could duplicate your knot (to keep a copy somewhere), in Edit mode shrink the mesh with alt S, select one edge loop then select the rest with ctrl i and delete with X, back to Object mode you convert the edge to curve (Object > Convert To > Curve

Comment: Well I have converted the mesh to curve, but I can't select the curve for the Array modifier,,,, working on this, do the ring and the taurus need to be the same object?

Comment: Related: [Modelling a full Windsor knot on a necktie](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/183459/78972)

Comment: So I'll follow the knot with a Bezier curve and then add curve modifier to the knot and target the Bezier, if I understand this correctly

Answer (score 3):

The process is rather simple. First take your torus knot, select one edge loop and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate by selection. Then you are left with 2 objects - the Knot and the "loop"

[image: Separate]

Then, you can delete the knot, leaving only the edge loop (if that's what you want). Select the loop and convert it to a curve.

[image: EdgeToCurve]

Then, add the mesh you want to repeat along the curve and give it an Array Modifier and a Curve modifier.  Make sure the curve is the second in the list. For the curve object, select the "curve" you made from the edge loop.

[image: ArrayFollow]

As usual, you can rotate/transform the "following mesh" (in edit mode) to give different effects.

[image: Orientation]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this almost works, I am just trying to get those rings around the torus knot. Adding the Curve modifier gets them out of shape, and twists them. I am actually very thankful, because that is a step forward :)

Comment: I just looked at your file. It looks like you positioned the ring around  the torus and applied the transforms. Unfortunately, this all works best when both the mesh and the curve have the same origin point (ideally (Global) 0,0,0). I was able to achieve some success by manually moving the ring back to the "world center" and applying all transforms there.

Comment: Yeah, I think I am having that problem. I am still too much of a noob to see this, but I will get there. This was really cool tutorial you made. Thank you very much for it :) Not giving up, but it is late here, and I want to relax a bit before going to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying multiple times to use arrays and curve modifier, changing the origin point of the rings without any success, I went with the "boring method", <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate and put in position:

[image]