Realistic Shoe lace animation
I stumbeled upon this video and I was wondering how to achieve such an animation of tieing a shoe lace: https://www.copenhagenstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2024/03/CPH40_leather_mix_off_white_light_blue_off_white_light_rose_CPH46_leather_mix_cream_desktop.mp4
It seems there is also a cloth sim added to a rigged shoe lace. Does anybody have a clue how this might have been done? My attempts to rig a shoe lace (even without physics) have not been very successful yet.
Thanks in advance!
Dario

Use a curve with the vertices hooked to bones or empties?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183459/modelling-a-full-windsor-knot-on-a-necktie/

Okay, thanks for the info!
